# react-native-vision-camera ANDROID BUILD ERRORS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

Hello everyone I'm trying to build react native android and I got three errors while doing it. Every error is related with the react-native-vision-camera . And sadly I couldn't find any solution on other questions.

Here is my error outputs:

```
error: package com.mrousavy.camera.frameprocessor does not exist import com.mrousavy.camera.frameprocessor.FrameProcessorPlugin;
error: cannot find symbol public class VisionCameraCodeScannerPlugin extends FrameProcessorPlugin
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @Override
```

And here is my current package dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"i18next": "^21.8.9",
"lottie-ios": "^3.2.3",
"lottie-react-native": "^5.1.3",
"mobx": "^5.15.7",
"mobx-react": "^6.3.1",
"native-base": "^3.4.6",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-i18next": "^11.17.1",
"react-native": "0.65.0",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
"react-native-hole-view": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
"react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.91",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.3.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0",
"yup": "^0.32.11" 
}
```

I'm pretty sure all errors that I stated above is related with the package react-native-vision-camera but I couldn't figure out how to solve them.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried following the troubleshooting guide on their documentation? https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/troubleshooting/